# ActiveCollab - failed to execute your request (reason DBConnectError)

Tags: php, activecollab, xampp

I'm trying to convert an ActiveCollab PHP application (which included the active collab source) to run on Windows XP on XAMMP which was previously run on a RedHat server. I've set up a virtual host and changed the config to point to the local database (which is loaded with the data and working).

However, when I run it, I get this error message:

Fatal error: activeCollab has failed to executed your request (reason: DBConnectError). Information about this error has been logged and sent to administrator.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can't believe it, I'm finding useful questions and answers from 2012. A client is still running an ancient copy of activeCollab, and I got the above error when I tried to move it to a new server. Thanks!

Comment: @clayRay same here, we were just migrating this piece of ancient history to a new server too.

Answer (score 4):

You can get more descriptive information about those kind of errors by accessing and updating your config at `activecollab/config/config.php` with....

```
define('APPLICATION_MODE', 'in_debug');
define('DEBUG', 2);
```

With newer versions you can do `define('APPLICATION_MODE', 'in_debug_mode');`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to migrate activeCollab, we recommend that you install a fresh copy, and than move the data from your old system. Exact migration instructions are provided here:

http://www.activecollab.com/docs/manuals/admin-version-3/tweak/moving-activecollab

If you are experiencing connection error problems, open config/config.php and make sure that your database connection parameters are good:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); // Database host, usually localhost
define('DB_USER', ''); // Database user account
define('DB_PASS', ''); // Database user password
define('DB_NAME', ''); // Name of the database where activeCollab tables are
```

Note that you should migrate your database content from Red Hat server to MySQL on your new Windows powered server (exporting SQL dump from one and importing to another should get you covered).